# SOAP request from Python

Tags: python, api, soap

guys!
I have a little problem, i'm trying to write python script to get catalog from one test service. I'm sending the request and receiving response with long xml body with description wsdl service, but it's not the result that i want to see) Someone, please, tell me what i'm doing bad)

Here is example how to use this service to get catalog:
[link1](http://snpy.in/ihIi8J)
[link2](http://snpy.in/nLAiGk)
Here is response from example:
[link3](http://snpy.in/9rxiiv)

Here is my script, that i had a problem with

```html
import requests

wsdl_url="https://apitest.merlion.com/re/mlservice3?wsdl"
#headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
params = {'login': 'TC0053432|API', 
 'password': 'XPE33UcS32',
 'encoding': 'UTF-8'
}

body = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="https://apitest.merlion.com/re/mlservice3"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <ns1:getCatalog>
  <cat_id xsi:type="xsd:string">All</cat_id>
 </ns1:getCatalog>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
"""

response = requests.post(wsdl_url, data=body, headers=params)

print(response)
print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get a SOAP client library first, not the requests.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices#SOAP

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my problem)